# Optimal Ways of Installing and Maintaining Ubuntu Installations while off line (Starting with DVDs)?

Tags: system-installation, package-management, dvd, offline

I got my installations from Raring Ringtail which offers Xubuntu, L, K, GNOME and Unity.  Let me also state that I know these version are already probably dated, since open source is always moving.

I would like to create a single installation, say Xubuntu, which I can do easily (have done so on dual boot and VitualBox on Windows 7) and get it up to date with 13.1 and 3rd party additions (at this point I will be in pub with internet ;).  Since I do not want to be too drunk after the base install, I will like to continue building out my installation back home on my SV.

My real challenge and real question to you is how to install from DVDs the additional software I already have available on these two DVDs, such as additional Windows Managers and the likes?  I don't want the latest (I can install updates from internet when I am connected again), I only want the exact versions on these DVDs to get me started with my image.

Having an Xubuntu base install, adding then Unity & Lubuntu (maybe others) from the DVD...Then look for other software that I wish to play with or substitute for those installed with these particular flavors.  So it would be good to not only be able to install, but easily examine what packages I would have available from the DVDs in hand?

So, for those still patient with me, to sum up:

1.) After base install be able to point my package manager to look at and tell me what packages I have available on my 2 DVDs?

2.) To install different flavors of Ubuntu windows managers, such as Unity, Lubuntu, Kubuntu, etc.?

3.) Install other desired applications (XBMC, File Manages, Utilities, etc.) that are not packages with the above selected Ubuntu flavors?

Thanks in advance to your understanding, patience and interest in helping out those trying to improve their knowledge and abilities with Ubuntu :)

Cheers!

Comment: As an after thought...I am starting my Ubuntu adventures using the two Raring Ringtail DVDs I got from an Ubuntu mag.  I see that upon running the installation when I have a previous installation I am given the option to "reinstall" ubuntu.  Q: Would this solve the first challenge of installing different window managers into the same instance of Ubuntu, without adverse effects?